# XML Xquery How to remove string before a specific character?

Tags: sql-server, xml, replace, xquery

I am trying to replace partial data of an element in xquery.

In my Database (Sql Server 2017) i have a table which contains a thousand XML.

Please find bellow one example of my XML

```xml
<Policies>
    <Policy>
        <GroupUserName>WERD\AA12BB34</GroupUserName>
        <GroupUserId>AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAMAdSpoMScJXq9mQyj30AAA==</GroupUserId>
        <Roles>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 1</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 2</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 3</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 4</Name>
                <Description>Enter description
            </Role>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 5</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
        </Roles>
    </Policy>
    <Policy>
        <GroupUserName>NTKD0\BB159FFN</GroupUserName>
        <GroupUserId>AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAALZBmswQnK326hQEyvt0JAA==</GroupUserId>
        <Roles>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 1</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
        </Roles>
    </Policy>
</Policies>
```

let focus on this part
I need to remove all characters before this " \ "

```xml
<GroupUserName>WERD\AA12BB34</GroupUserName>
<GroupUserName>NTKD0\BB159FFN</GroupUserName>
```

expected

```xml
<GroupUserName>AA12BB34</GroupUserName>
<GroupUserName>BB159FFN</GroupUserName>
```

so far i've done :

```sql
SELECT XmlDescription,
    replace(CAST(XmlDescription AS VARCHAR(8000)),'<GroupUserName>WERD\','<GroupUserName>')
from xml_temp 
WHERE ID = 1;
```

I have tried also:

```sql
replace(CAST(XmlDescription AS VARCHAR(8000)), '^.*\', '')
```

but nothing happened....

In sql i used to do :

```sql
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(myField, CHARINDEX('\', myField), LEN(myField)), '\', '')
```

I'm Trying to implement this method with xquery

Can you help me ?

Regards,

```sql
create table dbo.xml_temp (
    ID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    XmlDescription xml not null
);
insert into dbo.xml_temp (ID,XmlDescription) values (NEWID(),'<Policies>
    <Policy>
        <GroupUserName>WERD\AA12BB34</GroupUserName>
        <GroupUserId>AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAMAdSpoMScJXq9mQyj30AAA==</GroupUserId>
        <Roles>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 1</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>         
        </Roles>
    </Policy>
    <Policy>
        <GroupUserName>NTKD0\BB159FFN</GroupUserName>
        <GroupUserId>AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAALZBmswQnK326hQEyvt0JAA==</GroupUserId>
        <Roles>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 1</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
        </Roles>
    </Policy>
</Policies>')
```

```sql
SELECT @@version
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Is that `<GroupUserName>` element values follow some kind of pattern: WERD\AA12BB34, NTKD0\BB159FFN? Unfortunately, SQL Server XQuery doesn't support the `substring-before()` function.

Comment: I've checked in Table, i've found other value : WTXR4\. It doesn't seem to follow any particular pattern.
I've found this function ````substring-before()````, I was hoping to use it

Comment: So you have real values like: WTXR4, NTKD0, and the like before the backslash. Do they always have the same length, i.e. 5?

Comment: Yes it's real value. As u can see there are 3 values, two of them have a length of 5 and the other only 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is a workaround (kludge) because SQL Server XQuery doesn't fully support even XQuery v.1.0

In our case the `substring-after()` function is missing.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Policies>
    <Policy>
        <GroupUserName>WERD\AA12BB34</GroupUserName>
        <GroupUserId>AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAMAdSpoMScJXq9mQyj30AAA==</GroupUserId>
        <Roles>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 1</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 2</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
        </Roles>
    </Policy>
    <Policy>
        <GroupUserName>NTKD0\BB159FFN</GroupUserName>
        <GroupUserId>AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAALZBmswQnK326hQEyvt0JAA==</GroupUserId>
        <Roles>
            <Role>
                <Name>Role 1</Name>
                <Description>Enter description.</Description>
            </Role>
        </Roles>
    </Policy>
</Policies>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
, xmldata.query('<Policies>
{
    for $x in /Policies/Policy
    return <Policy>
        <GroupUserName>{
          if (contains(($x/GroupUserName/text())[1],"WERD")) then substring(($x/GroupUserName/text())[1],6,100)
          else substring(($x/GroupUserName/text())[1],7,100)
        }
        </GroupUserName>
        {$x/*[local-name()!="GroupUserName"]}
    </Policy>
}
</Policies>') AS Result
FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: I need to keep values after the backslash. With your SQL we keep the value before backslash.

Comment: @raoh, I updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Now it's good :), thank you for your time.
I'm just wondering is there any way to do : ````SUBSTRING(GroupUserName,CHARINDEX('\',GroupUserName)+1,LEN(GroupUserName)) ````?

Comment: @raoh, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote the following suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: @raoh, the answer on your question is NO. It is because the XML has multiple `<GroupUserName>` elements.